# Paperclip - Broken Image for "Missing.png"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, paperclip, image-uploading

I'm trying to setup the default image for my user's avatars and running into the problem of it not showing up in my view(s). My `user.rb` file is setup exactly how its shown on its Github page

```
has_attached_file :avatar, default_url: "/assets/:style/missing.png"
```

I also created a `paperclip.rb` file inside my `initializer` directory with the code below:

```
Paperclip::Attachment.default_options[:default_url] = "/images/missing.png"
```

I proceeded to place my png file `missing.png` in my `assets/images` folder but no luck. I then decided to create an images folder within my public directory, `public/images/missing.png` but still got a broken image. With each change I've reset my rails server with no avail. Unlike the posts on here similar to the issue I'm not receiving any errors in particular, just an image not being found . What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution involved two steps.

1. Since I'm using `default_url` in my user model there was no need to have nor include `paperclip.rb` for this particular scenario
2. Instead of using the url path specified by the wiki I put the image in my `public/images` directory and used: `default_url: "missing.png"` and everything worked.

Special thanks to Jared L Cowan's for the advice in the comment secion of his post

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
has_attached_file :avatar, default_url: "/assets/:style/missing.png"
```

Implies that for all styles, you should have an image :

```
/assets/thumb/missing.png
/assets/big/missing.png
```

The `default_options` is useless in this case because you override it in the `has_attached_file` line.

Just set an image per style, or change your default_url to `/assets/images/missing.png`.

Comment: Thanks I'll try this now. Also, should images like these be put in the public directory or the asset pipeline? Which directory is most common?

Answer (score 0):

To add on to ForgetTheNorm's answer.

I think it's best to put the image in the `public` directory. Otherwise if you put it in `assets/images` you'll need to change the `config.serve_static_assets` to `= true`.

You can change that in `config/environments/production` around line `23`

Also, you can add this 3 lines of jquery as a solution, or as an added measure to prevent broken images.

```
$("img").error(function() {
  $(this).unbind("error").attr("src", "PUT_YOUR_FOLDER_OR_URL_PATH_HERE");
});
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question in ForgetTheNorm's post. Is there a rule of thumb on where to put certain images when it comes to the `public` and `assets` directories?

Comment: I would double check as I have only been doing rails for like 7months or something, but if it's an image that is used outside of your normal CSS (like for errors) put it in public. Don't put images that you use for your background etc.

Here are some links that might help.
- https://www.reinteractive.net/posts/116-12-tips-for-the-rails-asset-pipeline
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8804225/when-to-put-images-to-app-asssets-and-when-to-public-images-in-rails-3-1
- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7597812/image-showing-as-blank-in-rails-3-1-on-production-heroku?rq=1

Comment: Welcome. Hope it helps.